# How to view SQL Server Compact Edition 4 blob data in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server CE 4.0 table that has a text blob field (ntext).  When I browse the data in VS 2010 SP1 the ntext field does not show any data.

Is there any way to view the blob data in VS 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ntext data is displayed as text using Show Table Data in VS 2010 SP1, but image data is displayed as "Binary Data". The SQL Server Compact Toolbox can display images with the "Edit Table Data" feature.

Comment: Hi Erik - I have ntext data that is showing as a blank cell when using Show Table Data under 2010 SP1.  Should I expect to see the data in the cell?

Comment: Yes, try Northwind - Categories - maybe there is no data!?

Comment: Yes, there is data - checked it in the lovely Data Port Console.  Guess my VS installation must be screwed :(